# SSRS Tables - Grouping Part Numbers without showing properties until list is dropped down

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-grouping

I was wondering if it is possible to have a SSRS table where I group by the part number and all preceding field's values will show after I click on the drop down? Currently I have a list grouped by part numbers and the parts requirements show on the same line.

How it would look like is this:

```
|Part Number||Requirement|Value|
--------------------------------
   +ab1
```

Dropped down it would look like this:

```
|Part Number||Requirement|Value|
--------------------------------
   -ab1    
                  r1      200
                  r2      100
```

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is called a toggle.  You need to set the toggle for the visibility for the grouping rows to be controlled by the part number text box.

If you read the following article it shows you how to do it:

[Toggling Visibility](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156456%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)